# Erro de divisão por zero - Query SQL

Tags: jquery, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte consulta abaixo, porém, quando eu a executo, ocorre a seguinte mensagem: `erro de divisão por zero`. Tentei utilizar a função `nullif`, mas sem sucesso. Como solucionar?

```
SELECT count(f.SolID) / cast(dbo.horas_uteis_trabalhadas('01-11-2017','30-11-2017') / nullif(144000,NULL) AS decimal(7,1)) [DPI]
FROM tarefa f
```

Comment: são um campo de data inicial e data final

Comment: Você pretende arrendondar em quantas casas decimais?

Comment: 7 igual como está na consulta. decimal (7,1)

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda @Marconi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testar se é nulo não vai lhe ajudar muito da forma como você está fazendo, pois se o valor das horas úteis continuar zero, você ainda vai ter o erro de divisão por zero.

Muito provavelmente sua função `horas_uteis_trabalhadas` deva estar retornando um inteiro ou um valor menor que 144000 e no sql server ao dividir um valor qualquer por um inteiro, ele sempre retornará um inteiro, que no seu caso será zero.

O que você pode fazer, é testar se as horas uteis trabalhas é maior que zero, montei um exemplo usando o case e fazer um `cast` para `float`:

```
with v1 as (
  select  
    cast(dbo.horas_uteis_trabalhadas('01-11-2017','30-11-2017') as float) as horas,
    cast(nullif(144000,null) as float) as valor,
    count(f.SolID) as SolId
  from tarefa f)

select iif(horas > 0, SolId / cast(horas/valor as float), 1) as [DPI] 
from v1
```

Comment: ôpa amigo, ocorreu o mesmo erro.

Comment: Fiz uma edição na minha resposta, usando iif, se possível, roda usando um `select * from v1` e poste o resultado na pergunta.

Comment: Eu acho que apenas trocando o `NULL  para `0` dentro do T-Sql `NULLIF` já resolveria o problema dele. Mesmo que `horas_uteis_trabalhadas` retorne `0` não dá erro. `0/AlgumNumero` é 0, ao contrario ocorrerá o erro da pergunta.

Comment: se horas uteis retornar 0, ele vai dar zero ao dividir pelo nullif, e ao tentar dividir o count(f.SolId) pelo resultado de horas/nullif vai dar erro de novo.

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas sim, tens razão. Pode ser que a query esteja assim: `count(f.SolId) / (0/144000)`

Comment: de toda forma aqui `nullif(144000,null)`sempre retornará 144000. Veja na documentação : https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql

Comment: Sim, esse nullif ta sendo usado de uma forma inutil no caso dele, vou até editar a minha resposta

Comment: show de bola @PabloTondolodeVargas, tudo certo.